# Tax Calculation in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, tax-rounding, tax-calculation

I want the total tax amount must be equal if I calculate it via grandtotal incl. Tax.

Like:

```
Product Ordered :  P1 = $10 (Incl. Tax) P2 = $20 (Incl. Tax)

Subtotal = $30 Shipping = $30 (Incl. Tax)
 Grand total Incl Tax : $60 
Total Tax(7%) : $3.92 (I want this should be 3.93) 
Grand total excl. Tax : $56.08 (It should be 56.07)
```

Because I set same tax class for both Shipping and Products.
**Set Tax rate to 7%.**

```
When I calculate 60 * 7 /107 = 3.9252 = 3.93
```

But I guess in **magento** it is like :

```
Product total tax via row total = 30 * 7 /107 = 1.9626 = 1.96 
Shipping tax = 30 * 7 /107 = 1.9626 = 1.96 
Total Tax = 1.96 + 1.96 = 3.92 (That is different if I calculate it on grand total)
```

(I don't want to round tax individually, I want to round the total tax amount (Product tax + shipping))

Suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: go to `admin>system>configuration>sales>tax->Shopping Cart Display Settings`  set what you want...

Comment: You want to calculate `tax` for `GST`

Comment: @RameshS Yes, Tax for GST

Comment: Okay then see `Manage Tax Rules` in `sales>tax`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/geblso like this